# CSS Grid Availability in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: css, internet-explorer, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, css-grid

I created a UI using CSS Grid, testing it in Chrome. I am migrating it to Sharepoint 2013 and trying to get it working the same but my grid structure was not maintained.

Grid is supported in IE, but is it not available in Sharepoint?

Comment: Hi, the f12>Emulation tab will tell you which IE version your sharepoint 2013 site/page is using and how it was established... its probably NOT using IE11 emulation. CSS Grid will work only when the website is using IE10 emulation or higher.

Comment: @RobParsons The Document Mode is currently set at 10. I toggled it to Edge but that made no changes.

Comment: Use the DOM Explorer of the dev tool to confirm that the grid style rules are applied (or over-ridden). you can feature test support with a script snippet like. 'grid' in document.body.style.... It's a good idea to post a reproduction url or a code snippet with your questions.